# read and write in external storage (sd card) in mobile (Not phone memory like Samsung 64 GB)

Tags: sd-card, android-external-storage

I want to read and write a file in the phone's external memory, but using the following code, I can only read and write in the phone's memory.
And with the available functions, you can only access the address of the phone's memory
I would be grateful if someone could help

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1
    private val filename = "SampleFile.txt"
    private val filepath = "MyFileStorage"
    var myExternalFile: File? = null
    var sdexternal : String?=null
    val  context: Context =this

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //        val sdCardState = Environment.getExternalStorageState()
    //        if (sdCardState == Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) {
    //            println("SD card is mounted and writable")
    //        } else if (sdCardState == Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY) {
    //            println("SD card is mounted but read-only")
    //        } else {
    //            println("SD card is not mounted")
    //        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////

        val readPermission = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        val writePermission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, readPermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, writePermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)    {
            // Permissions already granted, proceed with accessing external storage
            accessExternalStorage()
        } else {
            // Request permissions at runtime
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(readPermission, writePermission),   STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE)
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       val filename="file5111.txt"
//       val sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
//        //val sd= Environment.getExternalStorageState()
//        //val sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
//        //
//      //val filePath = "storage/emulated/1/file" // Replace with the actual path to your text file
//        val filePath = "$sdCardRoot"  //FOR ROOT-  COMMAND MAIN
//
//      //  val file = File(filePath)
//        val file = File(filePath, filename)
//
//        if (file.exists()) {
//                val fileContent = readFromFile(file)
//                println("File content: $fileContent")
//            } else {
//                println("File not found")
//                createFile(file)
//                println("File created: $filePath")
//            }

    }

    private fun accessExternalStorage() {

        val directoryType = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
        val externalFilesDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(directoryType)
        val externalFilesDirPath = externalFilesDir?.absolutePath
        println("External files directory path: $externalFilesDirPath")

//        val externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
//        val stat = StatFs(externalStorageDirectory.path)
//
//        val blockSize = stat.blockSizeLong
//        val totalBlocks = stat.blockCountLong
//        val availableBlocks = stat.availableBlocksLong
//
//        val totalSize = blockSize * totalBlocks
//        val availableSize = blockSize * availableBlocks
//
//        println("Total memory size: ${formatSize(totalSize)}")
//        println("Available memory size: ${formatSize(availableSize)}")



        val filename="file111.txt"
        val sdCardRoot=externalFilesDirPath
        //val sdCardRoot = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath)

//        val sdCardRoot = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath,filename)
//        val sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)

//        val file1 = File("$sdCardRoot") // Replace with the actual path to your file or directory
//
//        val sizeInBytes = file1.length()
//        val sizeInKilobytes = sizeInBytes / 1024
//        val sizeInMegabytes = sizeInKilobytes / 1024
//        val sizeInGigabytes = sizeInMegabytes / 1024
//
//        println("Size: $sizeInBytes bytes, $sizeInKilobytes KB, $sizeInMegabytes MB, $sizeInGigabytes GB")
        //val sd= Environment.getExternalStorageState()
       // val sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        //
        //val filePath = "storage/emulated/1/file" // Replace with the actual path to your text file
        val filePath = "$sdCardRoot/reza/"  //FOR ROOT-  COMMAND MAIN
        //val filePath="/sdcard"

        //  val file = File(filePath)
        val file = File(filePath, filename)

        if (file.exists()) {
            val fileContent = readFromFile(file)
            println("File content: $fileContent")
        } else {
            println("File not found")
            createFile(file)
            println("File created: $filePath")
        }
    }

    private fun readFromFile(file: File): String {
        val reader = FileReader(file)
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        val buffer = CharArray(4096)
        var charsRead: Int

        try {
            while (reader.read(buffer).also { charsRead = it } != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append(buffer, 0, charsRead)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            reader.close()
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString()
    }

    fun createFile(file: File) {
        try {
            file.parentFile?.mkdirs()
            file.createNewFile()
            val writer = FileWriter(file)
            writer.write("This is a new file.")
            writer.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permissions granted, proceed with accessing external storage
                //accessExternalStorage()
            } else {
                // Permissions denied, handle accordingly

            }
        }
         }

    private fun formatSize(size: Long): String {
        val units = arrayOf("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB")
        var fileSize = size.toDouble()
        var unitIndex = 0

        while (fileSize > 1024 && unitIndex < units.size - 1) {
            fileSize /= 1024
            unitIndex++
        }

        return String.format("%.2f %s", fileSize, units[unitIndex])
    }
    private fun isExternalStorageReadOnly(): Boolean {
        val extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState()
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY == extStorageState
    }

    private fun isExternalStorageAvailable(): Boolean {
        val extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState()
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED == extStorageState
    }
```

}
And I have used different codes which are commented in the code up and even some codes have been deleted